# boot-clj watch build -> run jar - ok -> change code -> run jar - fail: could not locate class

Tags: clojure, boot-clj

I build jar with `boot build watch` command and then I am able to successfully execute it with `java -jar target/project.jar` command. After source code change and rebuild the execution fails with message

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate my_dir/foo__init.class or my_dir/foo.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.`

I have the following files structure

```
.
├── build.boot
└── src
    └── my_dir
        ├── core.clj
        └── foo.clj
```

**build.boot** content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env boot
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src"}
 :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]])

(deftask build
  "Builds an uberjar of that can be run with java -jar"
  []
  (comp
   (aot :all true)
   (pom :project 'boottest
        :version "0.0.1")
   (uber)
   (jar :main 'my-dir.core)
   (target :dir #{"target"})))
```

**foo.clj** content:

```
(ns my-dir.foo)
(defn f []
  (println "I am f"))
```

**core.clj** content:

```
(ns my-dir.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [my-dir.foo :as foo]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "first run")
  (foo/f))
```

Now I have `boot build watch` running and when I change the content of **core.clj** to e.g. `(println "second run")`, wait for the rebuild and run the resulting project.jar I get the *could not locate class* error mentioned above. Finally what works is to manually rebuild the code via `boot build` command and rerun but I'd like to do it with `boot watch build` and I quite don't understand why it is not be working that way. I am totally new to boot so I might be missing something obvious but still want to know. Any ideas?

**boot version**

```
http://boot-clj.com
Tue Nov 22 11:35:59 CET 2016
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.8.0
BOOT_VERSION=2.6.0
```